# Object's members' values change as soon as interrupt is fired

Tags: embedded, c++

I have a UART class that has instances of `Fifo`. What I notice is as soon as the UART IRQ handler is fired, the member variables of `Fifo` instance change. I can't think of putting breakpoint any further because things seem perfectly fine inside `Uart::init()`...and the next thing to happen is the IRQ handler.

```c
// uart.hpp
class Uart 
{
  Fifo rx;
  Fifo tx;
  public:
  void init();
  void irqHandler();
};

// uart.cpp
static Uart *pUart;

void Uart::init() 
{
  pUart = this;
  // verified Uart::rx's members are as expected
  // ...
}

void IRQ_Handler(void) 
{
  pUart->irqHandler();
}

void Uart::irqHandler() 
{
    // Uart::rx members seem to have changed here...
}

int main(void) 
{
  Uart uart;
  uart.init();
  while(1);
}
```

Comment: Where does pUart come from?  Surely you need to call the object method ie UART::irqhandler();

Comment: not sure what you question really is. `pUart` is a mere pointer that points to the current Uart instance

Comment: In what way have the 'member variables of Fifo' changed?

Comment: Reading the title I immediately suspect stack overflow. Or wrong calling convention, how does the compiler know that `void IRQ_Handler(void) ` is an interrupt? Which target is this?

Comment: Also please don't cross post the same question on multiple Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: I'm using the exact same IRQ handler that's in the vector table (not used exactly the same here tho) and the issue isn't that the IRQ isn't being called. and nRF52

Comment: Single step at the assembler level and verify the object pointer or see where things go wrong.  If you don’t know assembler, then its a good time to learn.

Comment: i still suck at ASM but really how do you track what really happened been the last init function and the IRQ handler?